# A table font size smaller than tiny?

Tags: tables, lyx, fontsize

I have looked and there are answers for LaTeX documents, but not a way to implement it in LyX. If I have a table and it just does not fit, is there a way to get a text size smaller than `\tiny` in LyX? I am inserting my table using insert -> float -> table, and it looks great just a LITTLE too small.

Comment: Using a smaller font might produce a very difficult to read table.

Comment: A LyX minimal example is always useful in questions like these: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Using the `graphicx` package you can scale a box/table to the size you want.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The table neatly fits and is VERY readable so a step down shouldn't hurt. Any ideas in LyX using insert -> table and then pasting in ERT for the table

Comment: @CJ12 Please consider doing your readers a favour and make sure the table fits without scaling. Can you redesign the table? Can you post an example of what you've got?

Comment: @CJ12: You sounds quite young. You should be aware that older people haven't such a good eyesight anymore and tiny text is a pain in the ass.  If you are writing a thesis consider the age of your examiner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to make sure your table becomes unreadable, you can use the `\fontsize` command to set the font size to whatever you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}[!h]
\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\hline
hat & einer & gemacht zu & werden um von & Buch Wollen & unter & auch so weiter \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\fontsize{1}{1}\selectfont
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: maximum tinyness]

Comment: not unreadable at all, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `graphicx` package to resize a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
This & that & another & more & something else & and yet more & another column & more columns & more and more columns & and still much much more\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

The syntax is:

```
\resizebox{<horizontal width>}{<vertical height>}{<box>}
```

The `!` tells the `\resizebox` to scale the vertical proportional to the horizontal rescaling.

Comment: How would this work in LyX? I am using insert -> table and then pasting in ERT for the table

Comment: As I understand it, you can add LaTeX code directly to you LyX document.